# How to update data in the user information list when using FBA

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, forms-authentication, user-information-list

I've got to support a SharePoint web application which uses FBA with a custom membership and a custom role provider to authenticate the user against two different LDAPs. The user data are only stored in the user information lists. The SSP user profiles are not used.

Now one of the users got married and therefore her surname got changed in the LDAP (the one where her information are stored). But this change doesn't get provisioned into the user information list.

I wondering what option I have to provision changes of user data to the user information list. I've already tried to update the last name of the user manually, but it seems as if certain information like surname, first name are not editable in the user information list. I tried to edit them as a site administrator.

So what option do I have to solve this problem? Being able to edit the information per hand would also be a solution but of course not the most preferred one.

Answer (score 0):

Not recomended by MS, but it will get you going...Go to the database and update the AllUserData where (nvarchar1 LIKE '%OldName%'). Also, update the UserInfo table where     (tp_Title LIKE '%OldName%').

Comment: Yes it's possible this way, but as you already mentioned it's not support by MS and therefore no option.